# Update payment methods in stripe

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am trying to add phone number inside the billing details object that exist inside a stripe payment method. So far I am able to get data of a payment method via email and type and now i am trying to send an update model in a separate method that will update the phone number in billing details. But I am getting this error

> "message":"No such PaymentMethod: 'cus_JztknPBEnl5h8x'","stack":"Error: No such PaymentMethod: 'cus_JztknPBEnl5h8x'\n    at Function.generate (/Users/mac/Desktop/Batch-Skip/batch-skip-tracing/server/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:40:16)\n    at IncomingMessage. (/Users/mac/Desktop/Batch-Skip/batch-skip-tracing/server/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:203:33)\n    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:481:28)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:387:35)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (domain.js:470:12)\n    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)","context":"payment-controller","method":"addNewCard","level":"error","timestamp":"2021-08-07 23:08:18 +0500"}

Here is my getPaymentDetails method

```
  public async getAllStripePayments(id: string): Promise<Stripe.Response<Stripe.ApiList<Stripe.PaymentMethod>>> {
    const paymentMethods = await this.stripeClient.paymentMethods.list({customer: id, type: 'card'});
    return paymentMethods;
  }
```

Here is the update Method

```
      public async updateStripePaymentMethods(id: string, updateModel: Stripe.PaymentMethodUpdateParams): Promise<Stripe.Response<Stripe.PaymentMethod>> {
        const paymentMethods = await this.stripeClient.paymentMethods.update(id, updateModel);
        return paymentMethods;
      }
```

Calling update method like this

```
const paymentMethod = await this.stripeApi.getAllStripePayments(stripeCustomer.id);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(paymentMethod));
    const updateModel = {
      billing_details: {
        phone: customerMeta.phoneNumber,
      },
    };
    const updatePaymentMethod = await this.stripeApi.updateStripePaymentMethods(stripeCustomer.id, updateModel);
    console.log(updatePaymentMethod);
```

The data returned from getPaymentDetails method looks like this

```
{
  "object": "list",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "card_xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "object": "payment_method",
      "billing_details": {
        "address": {
          "city": null,
          "country": null,
          "line1": null,
          "line2": null,
          "postal_code": "xxxxx",
          "state": null
        },
        "email": null,
        "name": null,
        "phone": null
      },
      "card": {
        "brand": "visa",
        "checks": {
          "address_line1_check": null,
          "address_postal_code_check": "pass",
          "cvc_check": "pass"
        },
        "country": "US",
        "exp_month": 7,
        "exp_year": 2026,
        "fingerprint": "rxyg7B0k7Wp2Komf",
        "funding": "credit",
        "generated_from": null,
        "last4": "4242",
        "networks": {
          "available": [
            "visa"
          ],
          "preferred": null
        },
        "three_d_secure_usage": {
          "supported": true
        },
        "wallet": null
      },
      "created": 1628359699,
      "customer": "cus_JztknPBEnl5h8x",
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {},
      "type": "card"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "url": "/v1/payment_methods"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `stripeCustomer.id` into `updateStripePaymentMethods` which calls `paymentMethods.update`  - this is why you're getting an error saying
`No such PaymentMethod: 'cus_123'`. This is a customer ID, not a payment method ID. The Payment Method update needs a payment method id.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/update

It appears that `paymentMethod` is actually a list of `paymentMethods` plural, so you need to pick one and supply that ID (or iterate and supply each ID in turn).

Comment: So I tried to add id of card in it now like this `paymentMethod.data[0].id` but I got an error `{"message":"This PaymentMethod was converted from a legacy Card object. You may not update the email or phone number of these PaymentMethods."`

Comment: The problem is when got the payment method there is just no id of payment method as it should start with the keyword "pm"

Comment: I think I got the problem. Since I am creating customer therefore a payment method is actually a legacy card object and legacy card object cannot be updated as the error says. So I guess I am on a dead end with this. What do you think about my finding?